# weka does not load c4.5 format files due to missing values

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I am trying to work on a data set which is c4.5 format see [here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/internet_ads/)

somehow weka does not load ad.names nor ad.data, it always keeps giving me error due to missing values "?"

I even tried load it with C45Loader.java, same error. 
in this case, what could I do?

I know I could replace "?" with mean of the class that value belongs to, but I dont want to go down that way, because it won't get me accurate result.

any suggestions?

update: i found what went wrong, it's the whitespace in " ?" causes issue. it's ok now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found what went wrong, it's the whitespace in " ?" causes issue. it's ok now